# How to define mutually-dependent classes?

Tags: c++, class, object

Lets suppose we have a class A, which will include another class B as an element;

```
//ClasA.h
#ifndef _A_HEADER
#define _A_HEADER
#include "ClassB.h"
class B;
class A
{
private:
    B b;
public:
    A();
};
#endif
```

and

```
//ClassA.cpp
#include "ClassA.h"
A::A(){}
```

Now, we want class B to have a pointer to class A. So we define class B as:

```
//ClassB.h
#ifndef _B_HEADER
#define _B_HEADER
#include "ClassA.h"
class A;
class B
{
private:
    A *a;
public:
    B();
};
#endif
```

and

```
//ClassB.cpp
#include "ClassB.h"
B::B(){}
```

This way, we would have a class A, which would contain an object B. And The object B would have a pointer back to class A . Unfortunately, this do not work. I get the following error:

*-ClassA.h:9:7: error: field ‘b’ has incomplete type. B b;*

How can i fix this? And, considering that i fix it, is it worth it to implement a system like this? I mean, it surely doesn't feel very elegant.

-

Comment: Use a forward declaration, and include in the translation units. Nothing generally wrong with the approach.

Comment: An assorted selection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162580/mutually-dependent-class-declarations , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535239/c-mutual-class-dependency , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901606/proper-way-to-include-when-there-is-a-circular-dependency

Comment: Revisit your design, it's broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to use a forward declaration on at least one class.

For example:

```
//ClassB.h
#ifndef _B_HEADER
#define _B_HEADER
class A;
class B
{
private:
    A *a;
public:
    B();
};
#include "ClassA.h"
#endif
```

> And, considering that i fix it, is it worth it to implement a system
>   like this?

There is typically nothing wrong with this approach, and sometimes it will be necessary.

In regards to the specific error you're seeing:

> -ClassA.h:9:7: error: field ‘b’ has incomplete type. B b;

That is because, you can't declare anything implementation specific when using forward declarations.  If you were using `B *b;`, you would probably get the error mentioned in the questions referenced in the comments.